# Spark streaming: using object as key in 'mapToPair'

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In my Spark Streaming application I receive the following data types:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1479740400000,
  "key": "power",
  "value": 50
}
```

I want to group by `timestamp` and `key` and aggregate the `value` field.

Is there any way of keying by an object rather than a string? I want to do something like the following:

```
JavaPairDStream<AggregationKey, Integer> aggregation = data.mapToPair(
    (PairFunction<DataObject, AggregationKey, Integer>) data -> {
        return new Tuple2<>(new AggregationKey(data), data.value);
    }
).reduceByKey(
    (Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>) (value1, value2) -> {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
);
```

But this way of trying to group doesn't work in Spark.

To get around this in the interim I'm doing `new AggregationKey(data).toString()`. I don't know if this is an acceptable solution or not.

Answer (score 2):

Any object can be used with `byKey` methods as long as:

- it can be serialized
- has consistent hash
- has meaningful equality